# Selenium Python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, debugging

I'm new to automation testing and decided to use `Tumblr` as my subject. I'm having trouble making the options appear, see image attached, and don't know what else to use.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmlug.png

The code I'm currently trying to run it to is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-area icon_arrow_carrot_down']").click()
```

I've also tried

```
find_element_by_class_name 
find_element_by_class_id 
implicitly wait
```

still get the same error.

Below is the error I'm getting.

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>    
>  File
> "C:\Users\pmevangelista\eclipse-workspace\Pytest\python1\PySel.py",
> line 37, in 
> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='dropdown-area icon_arrow_carrot_down']").click() 
>    
>  File
> "C:\Users\pmevangelista\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 365, in find_element_by_xpath
> return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)  
>  File "C:\Users\pmevangelista\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 855, in find_element
> 'value': value})['value']    
>  File "C:\Users\pmevangelista\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 308, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)  
>  File "C:\Users\pmevangelista\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 194, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='dropdown-area
> icon_arrow_carrot_down']"}   (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120
> (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT
> 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Any ideas?

Comment: How about using `div.dropdown-area.icon_arrow_carrot_down` as css locator? It can be done using the `find_element_by_css_selector` [I think - it's been a long time since I used Python.]

Comment: @demouser123 Yes!! This works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at least one of the problems is that there are more class values on this element and you are checking only part of the class which leads to the element not found error. This element looks this way on my end (see that `pinned-target` part you've missed):

```
<div class="dropdown-area icon_arrow_carrot_down pinned-target" data-js-clickablesavedropdown=""></div>
```

I would instead use a *CSS selector* which is more concise and deals with multi-valued attributes like `class` much easier. One possible way to locate the element would be to use the preceding `Post` button:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.create_post_button + .dropdown-area")
```

Or, the parent "save post" container:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".post-form--save-button .dropdown-area")
```

---

Note that to make things more reliable and to eliminate one other possible reason for the error, add an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for presence, visibility or clickability of the element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
dropdown = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".post-form--save-button .dropdown-area"))
)
dropdown.click()
```